# Vue is validating properties in a livewire component

Tags: vue.js, laravel-7, laravel-livewire

I am using livewire in a Laravel 7 and laravel-ui project.

I created a component with livewire like this:

```
 <livewire:task-steps :steps="$taskCategory->steps" />
```

This is the only component on the page and I am getting this error from vue:

[image]

I don't know why vue is validating that component's property. I tried to install livewire/vue but nothing works.

This is my app.js https://gist.github.com/LTroya/710bfbd95988003b441d533ccbe6106d

I don't know what else to do. I will appreciate any hint

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vue and livewire are competing over who owns the html.

You can tell vue to ignore a block with v-pre: https://v3.vuejs.org/api/directives.html#v-pre

Or you can tell livewire to ignore a block with wire:ignore, the following page will show examples of using it: https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/alpine-js#creating-a-datepicker

In your case, wrap the code in a div and use v-pre on it.

```html
<div v-pre>
...
</div>
```